# On a conjectured relationship between the least prime factor and the Euler prime of an odd perfect number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisibility, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(Note: This question has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249989).)

Let $\sigma$ be the classical sum-of-divisors function.  For example,
$$\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=12={2}\cdot{6}.$$

If $\sigma(N)=2N$ and $N$ is odd, then $N$ is called an *odd perfect number*.  Currently, the problem of the existence of odd perfect numbers is still open.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $N$ must have the form
$$N=q^k n^2,$$
where $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

[Dris [2008]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450) showed that the inequality 
$$\sigma(q^k) \leq \dfrac{2n^2}{3}$$
holds, and subsequent improvements were given by other authors ([Dris, Luca (2016)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1437), [Chen, Chen (2012)](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S0004972712000032), [Broughan, Delbourgo, Zhou (2013)](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf), and [Chen, Chen (2014)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266034679_On_the_index_of_an_odd_perfect_number)).

Let $p_1$ be the least prime factor of the odd perfect number $N$ with Euler prime $q$.  It is relatively easy to show that $p_1 \neq q$. Suppose to the contrary that the Euler prime $q$ is also the least prime factor of the odd perfect number $N$.  Since $\sigma(q) \mid \sigma(q^k) \mid \sigma(N) = 2N$, we get that
$$\dfrac{q+1}{2} = \dfrac{\sigma(q)}{2} \mid N,$$
so that $(q+1)/2$ divides $N$.  If $(q+1)/2$ is prime, then this will contradict the assumption that $q$ is the least prime factor of $N$ (as $(q+1)/2 < q$).  If $(q+1)/2$ is composite, then $(q+1)/2$ will have a prime factor (necessarily smaller) that *likewise divides* $N$. Again, this is a contradiction.  **QED**

Therefore, $p_1 < q$.

Here is my question:

> Will it be possible to either prove or rule out the following equality, using the current state of knowledge that we have on odd perfect numbers?
>   $$\dfrac{q+1}{2} = {p_1}$$

Comment: The calculation that I can get, **but doesn't solve nothing about your question** is: expand using Newton's Binomial theorem to get from $(q+1)^k= 2^kp_1^k$ then $$q^k+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{j}q^j=2^kp_1^k,$$ and from this (since one wants to use the inequality $\sigma(q^k)\leq \frac{2n^2}{3}$) then multiply by $q$, substract $1$ and dividing by $q-1$ one gets $$\sigma(q^k)+\frac{q}{q-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{j}q^j=\frac{q(2^kp_1^k)-1}{q-1},$$ and now one can use the inequality $\sigma(q^k)\leq \frac{2n^2}{3}$, and try deduce something  (!).

Comment: @user243301, that is a good start.  I invite you to write that out as an actual answer.

Comment: I understand that is only a contribution as a comment, is not an answer. I was writting those simple calculations because perhaps you can deduce something useful about the size or from the first of those identities something when you divide, or combining with different factors. Very thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, and takes off from the hint in user243301's [comment here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918855/on-a-conjectured-relationship-between-the-least-prime-factor-and-the-euler-prime#comment3993575_1918855).

---

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Let
$$n = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$
be the *canonical prime factorization* of $n$.  (That is, all of the $\alpha_i$'s are positive, and $p_1 < p_2 < \ldots < p_{\omega(n)}$ are prime numbers.)

Suppose to the contrary that
$$\frac{q+1}{2}=p_1.$$

user243301 obtained the following equation:
$$\sigma(q^k) + \frac{q}{q-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{j}q^j = \frac{q(2^k {p_1}^k) - 1}{q - 1},$$
where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

However, we know that we have the upper bound
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k} < \frac{q}{q-1}$$
since $q$ is prime.  This means that
$$\frac{q(2^k {p_1}^k) - 1}{q - 1} = \sigma(q^k) + \frac{q}{q-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{j}q^j > \sigma(q^k)\left(1 + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{j}q^{j-k}\right)$$
$$> \sigma(q^k)\cdot\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}q^{j-k}\right) = \sigma(q^k)\cdot{\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k}}.$$

This implies that
$$\frac{q(2^k {p_1}^k) - 1}{q^k (q - 1)} > \left(\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k}\right)^2 \geq \left(\frac{q+1}{q}\right)^2.$$

But the fraction $q/(q - 1)$ is bounded from above by
$$\frac{q}{q - 1} \leq \frac{5}{4}$$.

Hence, it follows that
$$\left(\frac{q+1}{q}\right)^2 < \frac{q(2^k {p_1}^k) - 1}{q^k (q - 1)} < \frac{q(2^k {p_1}^k)}{q^k (q - 1)} \leq \frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{2^k {p_1}^k}{q^k} = \frac{5}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{2p_1}{q}\right)^k = \frac{5}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{q+1}{q}\right)^k,$$
whence the inequality
$$\left(\frac{q+1}{q}\right)^{2-k} < \frac{5}{4},$$
or equivalently the inequality
$$\left(\frac{q}{q+1}\right)^{k-2} < \frac{5}{4}, \tag{1}$$
holds.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28q%2F%28q+%2B+1%29%29%5E%28k+-+2%29+%3C+5%2F4) then gives the following inequality plot:

[image: WolframAlpha inequality plot]

and the following real solutions (**???**) to Inequality $(1)$:

$$k > 2, q = 0$$
$$k = n_1 + 2, -1 < q < -\frac{\sqrt[n_1]{5}}{2^{2/{n_1}} + \sqrt[n_1]{5}}, n_1 \in \mathbb{Z}, n_1 \leq -1$$
$$k = n_1 + 2, -\frac{\sqrt[n_1]{5}}{2^{2/{n_1}} + \sqrt[n_1]{5}} < q < 0, n_1 \in \mathbb{Z}, n_1 \geq 1$$
$$k = n_2 + 2, -1 < q < 0, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$k < 2, q < -1.$$

(**Note that these real solutions violate $q \geq 5$.**)

But the minimum value for $q/(q+1)$ occurs at $5/6$ (for $q=5$), hence
$$\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{k-2} \leq \left(\frac{q}{q+1}\right)^{k-2} < \frac{5}{4}. \tag{2}$$

Solving Inequality $(2)$ for $k$ yields
$$k > \dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{144}{125}\right)}{\log\left(\dfrac{6}{5}\right)} \approx 0.776099,$$

which does not rule out $k=1$.

---

(*This answer is currently under construction.*)